# Calling an overloaded C# method that takes an Action<A> or a Action<A,B> from F#

Tags: f#, overloading, c#-to-f#

Here are the signatures of the two overloads.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextPool<TContext>(
    this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
    Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction,
    int poolSize = 128) where TContext : DbContext { ...

public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextPool<TContext>(
    this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
    Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction,
    int poolSize = 128)
    where TContext : DbContext { ...
```

Here is the 2nd overload being called in C#
[image]

But when I try to call the 2nd overload from F#, I get this error:

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Try passing `fun (sp: IServiceProvider) (optionsBuilder: ...) -> ...`

Comment: @AMieres Ulgh, that was it. Copy paste to an answer and I'll accept =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing:

```
fun (sp: IServiceProvider) (optionsBuilder: ...) -> ...
```